# Can I use a least squares polynomial fit on residuals to estimate variance?

Tags: regression, variance, residuals

Given some residuals, is there any problems with using a least squares polynomial fit to estimate the variance?

[image: Residual plots]

The resulting fit looks like this using `numpy.polyfit`

```py
import numpy as np

poly = np.polyfit(df.VALUES, df.SQ_RESIDUAL, 2)
plt.scatter(df.TOTAL, np.sqrt(np.polyval(poly, df.VALUES)), label='fit')
```

[image: Poly fit]

My goal is to ultimately generate random numbers using the expected value and the estimated variance.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What is the underlying model? Why do you get residuals like these and why can you assume that the variance follows a polynomial function? In addition, how are you gonna generate the random numbers? There are some additional assumptions there? And what are you gonna use it for?

Comment: Also, note that your polynomial fit is relatively flat. It ranges from 9.75 to 11.50 and is not showing the shape that you observe in the plot (maybe this is something that you were expecting). It might be very well that you actually just have a relatively constant variance, and it is due to the lower number of points in the sample at the values away from the center (close to 95 or 130) that you get this shape.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus These are Vegas expected points scored for an NBA team, so I don't have access to the underlying model only their expected values and the residuals. I wanted to just generate samples given the expected value and variance using a normal distribution

Comment: NBA team stands, I guess, for National Basketball Association team. But I do not understand anything about the rest. What are 'Vegas expected points'? Why don't you have a model for what you are trying to model? Why do you 'just want to generate samples', what's the point of that?

Comment: It is very difficult to perform statistics without a statistical model, and to create a statistical model you can not just ask a statistician about what model you should use. It requires the combination of statistical knowledge *and* domain knowledge to come up with a feasible statistical model. Your question doesn't provide much information about this domain knowledge. So, an answer could be 'yes you can model the variance with a regression' but *why* you should do this is completely unclear.

Comment: "Vegas expected points" is the betting line that is set by sportsbooks of how many points a team is expected to score. I wanted to see if it was feasible given two teams expected points ex) 102 and 110 to generate random samples of each teams scores to see the possible outcomes the game can take. Since I do not have access to the underlying model used by sportsbooks I wanted to know if it's possible to do this with only the expected values and residuals.

Comment: Using a polynomial model for the variance would be just an arbitrary guess about the underlying model and it is difficult to say whether this is correct or not. The motivation is important and that requires domain knowledge. E.g. knowing that these are basketball scores one could try to better argue about a good model.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably bootstrap the residuals as an alternative to a poly-fit.

but ....

1. Small samples are not great for bootstrap so maybe try an alternative.
2. you can fit a polynomial to the histogram, but it is probably better to make a parameterized distributional assumption

Why not fit a normal distribution to a histogram of your residuals. If your sample size is small you may want to start with a normal assumption.

Comment: Say the expected value was 120, is there a more sophisticated/better alternative to just taking all residuals where expected value was 120 and then sampling those? Because certain expected values won't have a lot of samples